Can't get Flutter GetX / Obx to update widget when splitting into parent and child widget
I have a widget that shows a countdown timer. It works perfectly fine when all of the code is in the parent widget. However, I've been trying to make it more modular by moving the days/hours/minutes/seconds to a child element, and I can't get it to update the child widgets.
Here's the original code which works perfectly fine:
                          Obx(
                            () => controller.keyReading[controller.selectedItem].nextReadingMinutes != null &&
                                    controller.keyReading[controller.selectedItem].nextReadingMinutes! > 0
                                ? Container(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border.all(color: AppColors.black, width: 0.5),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.33)),
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(
                                              height: 50.h,
                                              child: Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                children: [
                                                  Column(
                                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                    children: [
                                                      AppWidgets.setTextWidget(controller.days.value,
                                                          lines: 1,
                                                          align: TextAlign.left,
                                                          styles:
                                                              Get.theme.textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(color: AppColors.colorWhite, fontSize: 16.sp)),
                                                      Expanded(
                                                        child: AppWidgets.setTextWidget("strDays".tr,
                                                            lines: 2,
                                                            align: TextAlign.left,
                                                            styles: Get.theme.textTheme.bodySmall
                                                                ?.copyWith(color: AppColors.colorWhite, fontSize: 12.sp)),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                          // Repetition of the previous SizedBox for hours, minutes, and second
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 8,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ))
                                  // Logic for alternative cases -- irrelevant here
                                )

This is the new way I'm trying to do it. Here is the child widget:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:Fortuna/shared/custom_widgets/app_widgets.dart';
import 'package:Fortuna/shared/values/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

class TimeColumnWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String value;
  final String label;

  TimeColumnWidget({required this.value, required this.label, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        AppWidgets.setTextWidget(
          value,
          lines: 1,
          align: TextAlign.left,
          styles: Get.theme.textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(color: AppColors.colorWhite, fontSize: 16.sp),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: AppWidgets.setTextWidget(
            label.tr, // Static label translation
            lines: 2,
            align: TextAlign.left,
            styles: Get.theme.textTheme.bodySmall?.copyWith(color: AppColors.colorWhite, fontSize: 12.sp),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

I then use it in the parent like this:
                          Obx(
                            () => controller.keyReading[controller.selectedItem].nextReadingMinutes != null &&
                                    controller.keyReading[controller.selectedItem].nextReadingMinutes! > 0
                                ? Container(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border.all(color: AppColors.black, width: 0.5),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.33)),
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(
                                              height: 50.h,
                                              child: Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                children: [
                                                  TimeColumnWidget(value: controller.minutesData.value, label: "strMinutes"),
                                          // Repetition for hours, minutes, and second
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 8,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ))
                                  // Logic for alternative cases -- irrelevant here
                                )

If I do this, it doesn't update the timer, even though it did in the original.
I tried several things to make it work. I tried wrapping the TimeColumnWidget in Obx:
Obx(() => TimeColumnWidget(value: controller.minutesData.value, label: "strMinutes")),

I also tried removing the outer Obx and just having this one.
I also tried making the TiemColumnWidget reactive, like this, with and without Obx in the parent widget, but this didn't work either:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:Fortuna/shared/custom_widgets/app_widgets.dart';
import 'package:Fortuna/shared/values/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

class TimeColumnWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final RxString value;
  final String label;

  TimeColumnWidget({required this.value, required this.label, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        // Reactive Text Widget
        Obx(() => AppWidgets.setTextWidget(
          value.value, // Observe changes in RxString
          lines: 1,
          align: TextAlign.left,
          styles: Get.theme.textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(color: AppColors.colorWhite, fontSize: 16.sp),
        )),
        Expanded(
          child: AppWidgets.setTextWidget(
            label.tr, // Static label translation
            lines: 2,
            align: TextAlign.left,
            styles: Get.theme.textTheme.bodySmall?.copyWith(color: AppColors.colorWhite, fontSize: 12.sp),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Any ideas? Thanks so much in advance for any help.

OK I figured it out. You have to pass in the regular String in the constructor for Get to realize that it is being rebuilt. So you have to do this:
class TimeColumnWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String value;
  final String label;

  TimeColumnWidget({required this.value, required this.label, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        AppWidgets.setTextWidget(
          value,
          lines: 1,
          align: TextAlign.left,
          styles: Get.theme.textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(color: AppColors.colorWhite, fontSize: 16.sp),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: AppWidgets.setTextWidget(
            label.tr, // Static label translation
            lines: 2,
            align: TextAlign.left,
            styles: Get.theme.textTheme.bodySmall?.copyWith(color: AppColors.colorWhite, fontSize: 12.sp),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

And call it like this:
Obx(() => TimeColumnWidget(value: controller.minutesData.value, label: "strMinutes")),

Obx has to be immediately around the .value conversion for Get to rebuild the Widget.
